# Deleting post from database using SQLAlchemy gives error: "Object '...' is already attached to session"

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to delete posts from a database using the posts ID but I keep getting the following error.

sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: Object '' is already attached to session '34' (this is '35').

What im trying to do should be very simple but I've not used SQLAlchemy enough to be sure of what this means and how to fix it.

I have a route to delete the post that looks like this:

```
@app.route('/delete_post')
def delete_post():

    post_id = request.args.get('post_id')

    deleted_post = posts.query.filter_by(id=post_id).first()
    db.session.delete(deleted_post)
    db.session.commit()

    flash('Post deleted!', 'success')
    return redirect(url_for('admin_posts'))
```

All the route is supposed to do is get the post_id variable from the URL passed from the previous page, queries the database to find all posts that have an id of post_id and delete the matching post. I just keep getting the error I posted above.

I don't think the problem lies in the code, it should be working according to my understanding. I think the problem is something to with the SQLAlchemy db.sessions and that I have misused it somehow.

I should also note that I have used SQLAlchemy many times in the rest of the app for the creating of posts, replies and accounts and they all work. The issue is just with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I got it working, the problem was with my imports...

I'm not sure why or more importantly HOW this was the case but, I didn't correctly import from my init.py in my routes.py.

I had:

```
from app import app
```

But needed:

```
from app import app, db
```

Obvious and silly mistake, but I thought everything was working fine since all of my other SQLAlchemy features were working such as inserting and querying... very strange.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are unintentionally creating 2 sessions, and sticking the same object into both sessions.

This line here

```
posts.query.filter_by(id=post_id).first()
```

Is most likely using one session (it's difficult to say w/o this model code).

Then

```
db.session.delete(deleted_post)
```

is likely using a different session.

The solution is to use the same session for both operations.

Try importing the session the `posts` model uses from the module it is in.

Comment: Yes, seems like that probably is the cause of the error.

But "The solution is to use the same session for both operations", how can I do that? I should also note that I've got a lot of SQLAlchemy functionality already implemented to the app. Such as making posts, replies, login/registration system.